# How do I delete all UNUSED images from my uploads directory if do not saved in Database in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

> I use laravel 4.2

I have more than 1,000 images in the project; these images have been occupied by host users after multiple uploads. Please edit the sample instance in such a way that it will erase all images except images that have both the name and the file stored.

```
public function del_image()
    {

        $scan = scandir('uploads/evidence');


        foreach($scan as $file)
        {
            if (!is_dir($file))
            {
                $list = DB::table('evidence')
                ->where('profile_img',$file)
                ->select('profile_img')->get();

              echo '<pre>';print_r($list); echo '</pre>';   
            }
        }

        //echo $list."<br>";
        //echo '<pre>';print_r($list); echo '</pre>';   

    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $scan = scandir('uploads/evidence');
    $files =  DB::table('evidence')->pluck('profile_img');
    $protectTheseImages = [];
    foreach($files as $file) {
        $protectTheseImages[] = $file;
    }

    $diff = array_diff($scan, $protectTheseImages);
    foreach($diff as $file) {
        if (!is_dir($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192070/discussion-on-answer-by-safak-ciplak-how-do-i-delete-all-unused-images-from-my-u).

Comment: $diff = array_diff($scan, $protectTheseImages);
echo '<pre>'; print_r($diff); die; you'll be show will delete file names. everything is ok. you can execute this code :)

Comment: Can you success ?

Comment: I have not succeeded yet

Answer (score 1):

I think You should use this code.

```
$scan = scandir('uploads/evidence');
$files =  DB::table('evidence')->pluck('profile_img');
$protectTheseImages = [];


foreach((array)$files as $file) {
    $protectTheseImages[] = $file;
}

//dd($protectTheseImages);

$diff = array_diff($scan, $protectTheseImages);
foreach($diff as $file) {
    if (!is_dir($file)) {
        echo $file."<br>";

        $image_path = '/folder_path/uploads/evidence/'.$file; 
        unlink($image_path);
    }
}
```

Hope This Code Helps you.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but in line $files =  DB::table('evidence')->pluck('profile_img'); show all images in directory !!!

Answer (score 0):

this code i updated to :

```
$scan = scandir('uploads/evidence');
        $files =  DB::table('evidence')->pluck('profile_img');
        $protectTheseImages = [];


        foreach((array)$files as $file) {
            $protectTheseImages[] = $file;
        }

        //dd($protectTheseImages);

        $diff = array_diff($scan, $protectTheseImages);
        foreach($diff as $file) {
            if (!is_dir($file)) {
                echo $file."<br>";
                //unlink($file);
            }
        }
```

but, line `echo $file."<br>";` just show all images in directory !!!

Comment: Are you sure? If you can get success your dB files it should be correct I test it

Comment: yes, in line $files =  DB::table('evidence')->pluck('profile_img'); must show just "profile_img" but show all images in directory !!!

Comment: Yes these are protect files. after that you can see second foreach $file. These are will be deleted files.